# Using regex to get the text of a string but excluding the last part?

Tags: ruby, regex, nokogiri

I used something like this:

```
.text[/(\S+) Results$/i, 1]
```

To get the `536,087` part of the following:

> Showing 1 - 24 of 536,087 Results

How should I modify that code in order to get the `Movers & Shakers` part in the following:

```
Movers & Shakers in <span class="category">Baby Products</span>
```

(in other words, excluding the `in`).

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: give some more and full html please

Comment: @Babai I added more HTML.

Comment: ok.. now tell which value you want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this.

```
t = 'Movers & Shakers in <span class="category">Baby Products</span>'
t[/(.*?)(?=\sin)/, 1]

=> "Movers & Shakers"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.*(?=\sin\s<span)
```

Will match anything before an in span on the line.
Demo: http://rubular.com/r/bXitHsTPuB